# Can't get the names of users who comments my live video with Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, request, live

Hello i'm blocked at a point in my facebook app,

I try to get names from users who comments my live video as a page manager who launch the live. I try to make the request with my page access token in parameter of the request but change nothing, i only get name if its me who comments the live.. Any idead of what i'm doing wrong ? (sorry for bad english.. :D)

```
checkForComments: function () {
    let self = this;
    FB.api('/' + encodeURIComponent('746684572339136/comments'), {access_token:self.accessTokenPage}, function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (response && !response.error) {
        let comments = response.data;
        if (comments && comments.length && self.comments.length !== comments.length) {
          for (let i = self.comments.length; i < comments.length; i++) {
            self.comments.push(comments[i]);
            console.log(comments[i]);

            //let name = comments[i].from.name;
            //if (self.influenceurs.indexOf(name) > -1){
             // self.money = self.money + 1000;
           // }
            //else {
              self.money = self.money + 1;
            //}
          }
          console.log(self.money)
        }

      }
      else {
        console.log('Get nothing')
      }

      setTimeout(function () {
        self.checkForComments()
      }, 20000)


    })
  },
```

EDIT : My facebook API version is 3.2, and i develop with vue.js :)

Comment: could be for data privacy reasons. are you surely using a page token of that page?

Comment: i think it's that in fact, yeah i have a page access token but i didnt submit my app to facebook, so i did it and i'm waiting, it's probably the thing to do :)